# Rails emailer track link clicks with Mixpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

We have mixpanel installed in our rails app, and I've worked out how to track email opens with the Mixpanel gem, but I can't figure link tracking from the emails.

I want to track that an email link has been clicked as a mixpanel event.

Any ideas?

Comment: If my answer works for you I'd be keen to find out how you implement. We're also working on tracking email campaigns with Mixpanel :)

Answer (score 0):

Mixpanel can track links using the `redirect` event request parameter of the HTTP tracking API [1].

> If present, Mixpanel will serve a redirect to the given url as a response to the request. This is useful when tracking clicks in an email or text message.
>
> This tracking call will be redirected to http://www.example.com when it responds:
>
> http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=eyJldmVudCI6ICJnYW1lIiwgInByb3BlcnRpZXMiOiB7ImlwIjogIjEyMy4xMjMuMTIzLjEyMyIsICJkaXN0aW5jdF9pZCI6ICIxMzc5MyIsICJ0b2tlbiI6ICJlM2JiNDEwMDMzMGMzNTcyMjc0MGZiOGM2ZjVhYmRkYyIsICJ0aW1lIjogMTI0NTYxMzg4NSwgImFjdGlvbiI6ICJwbGF5In19==&redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com

[1] https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http